# Changing Layout xml not changing content, only changing layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I had no idea what to call this question, what I am experiencing is a little odd, to say the least.

I have a layout with the following section part of it

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activityProjectView_projectName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Project name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activityProjectView_projectDueDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Project Due Date"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" /> 
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/activityProjectView_projectDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Project Description"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

In my code I assign the variables into these TextView elements as follows

```
TextView projectName = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.activityProjectView_projectName);
        TextView projectDesc = (TextView)
        this.findViewById(R.id.activityProjectView_projectDescription);
        TextView projectDueDate = (TextView) 
        this.findViewById(R.id.activityProjectView_projectDueDate);

        projectName.setText(project.getName());
        projectDesc.setText(project.getDescription());
        projectDueDate.setText(Util.DATE_SHORT_UI.format(project.getDueDate()));
```

The data returned by the project getters is correct.  When the view loads, the small textview is populated with the description, not the date and the medium textview is populated with the date not the description.

I thought this was odd as the view is correct, and the code by the looks of it is correct.  At this point I switched the layout so that the date element was below as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activityProjectView_projectName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Project name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activityProjectView_projectDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Project Description"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" /> 
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
            android:id="@+id/activityProjectView_projectDueDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Project Due Date"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

I expected this to switch the data round (showing that I had some sort of error in my code, or mis assignment somewhere).  I was wrong.  The data stayed exactly where it was previously.

By that I mean the date was now displayed in the other textview and same for description.  So now even though I switched the textviews round, the date was now in the the medium textview not the small one and the description switched also.  Oddly the view definitely updated as i saw the medium and small text views move places, but the data somehow also switched.

What is going on?  Whatever I do to my layout file, I can get the style itself to change, and position of elements, but the data always somehow finds a way to display itself in the wrong textviews.

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild your project from scratch (e.g. clean and build)? Looks like the R file got broken somehow and you may want to try to regenerate it.

Comment: @Egor thats what I thought but surely this would mean that the ids would point to the wrong layout element consistently?  Also whenever I have gone to clean the project in the past I have never managed to get it to rebuild my R file.  How can I ensure this would work?

Comment: As a last resort, you can manually remove the "build" directory if you're using Gradle, or remove everything from the "gen" directory if you're using Eclipse. This will make sure you'll be doing a clean build next time.

Comment: @Egor I am always worried about doing that as when I have done this in the past it won't ever rebuild.  The lack of R.java file causes compilation errors (as you would expect) and those compilation errors stop eclipse from building a new R.java file.

Comment: I thought I'd take the risk, and it did rebuild it (first time for me :) ) and it did sort the issue out.  I am still confused why though.  If you post an answer I will set it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the issue was caused by a broken R.java file with references pointing to wrong views. A clean rebuild fixed the issue.